# gsap.reverse() not working on onMouseLeave in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, animation, gsap

I am integrating simple gsap animations into my React application. I can trigger a `animation.play()` fn on `onMouseEnter`, but the `animation.reverse()` fn is not working.

Here's my set up:

```
const hoverScaleAnimation = (
ref: MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | null>
) => {
  return gsap.to(ref.current, { scale: 1.05 });
};

const onEnter = (ref: MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | null>) => {
  hoverScaleAnimation(ref).play();
};

const onLeave = (ref: MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | null>) => {
  hoverScaleAnimation(ref).reverse();
};
```

Originally I was just triggering new `gsap.to` animations in the hover functions, but I thought this would be cleaner/less need to calculate how to scale and de-scale.

I am following these [react & gsap guidelines](https://greensock.com/react/) from greensock, and tried to use `reverse()` in line with their recommendations [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hover-forward-ref-ybtgs) and [here](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/9083-how-do-i-resumereverse-tween-on-mouseout/).

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-morse-h1dj5?file=/src/components/Item/Item.tsx)

Answer (score 1):

Answered on the greensock forum: https://greensock.com/forums/topic/29212-gsapreverse-not-working-on-onmouseleave-in-react/

The solution is to create a tween, run it in `useEffect` but instantiate it as `paused`, then `play` and `reverse` on hover:

```
const itemRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
const tween = useRef<any>(null);

useEffect(() => {
  tween.current = gsap.to(itemRef.current, { scale: 1.05, paused: true});
}, []);

const onEnter = () => {
  tween.current.play();
};

const onLeave = () => {
  tween.current.reverse();
};
```